# Linux on the D330-10IGM

Tags: gnome, suspend

I am very new to ubuntu but I know much of before hand, I am currently using a lenovo tablet call as the D330-10IGM the discontinued ver and it originally shipped with windows but as the years went by windows became heavy and the tab couldn't handle at least 1 windows so, I wanted to switch to ubuntu but the only problem is when I try to install it. It is stuck in a black screen, and when I FINALLY got it working the only problem is that when I try to wake it from suspend it is staying in a black screen. I say this in an another form but I tried it atleast 1000x times but it is not working, and the device is stuttering. like graphics issues. I need help on this

Thanks so much in advance :)

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product, no release details, are you hoping we guess?  Ubuntu LTS releases also have kernel stack options, and for some *older* hardware I've found the choice you make really matters, but you've not said what you're actually using.

Comment: I sorry about that, I did'nt know

here is the ver
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

the kernel ver.
5.19.0-32-generic